# Why append function doesn't accept the same type data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Below code was created just to achieve something, Code is not yet finished but stuck in some other compiler error,

```
struct RowColumn {
    var row : Int
    var column : Int
    init(row : Int, column : Int) {
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
    }
}
let adjancencyMatrix = [[0,1,0,0],
                        [1,0,0,0],
                        [0,0,0,1],
                        [1,0,0,0]]

class CodeController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for column in 0...3 {
            solve(row: 0, column: column,visited: [RowColumn(row: 0, column: 0)])
        }
    }
    func solve(row : Int, column : Int , visited : [RowColumn] = []) {
        var visited  = visited
        if visited.count >= 4 {
            print("Solution available ")
        }else {
            if adjancencyMatrix[row][column] == 1 && !visited.contains(RowColumn(row: row, column: column)) {
                visited = visited.append(RowColumn(row: row, column: column))
                for possible in 0...3 {
                    solve(row: column , column:possible,visited: visited )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the holder array is of type [RowColumn], When I am trying to add an element , compiler throws me a error," *Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[RowColumn]'*"
in the following line  `visited = visited.append(RowColumn(row: row, column: column))`
What exactly the problem out here?

Comment: Remove “visited =“.

Comment: Append modified the array in place. (Sorry for bad code formatting, away from computer)

Comment: thanks got it was a miss from my side  and was blaming compiler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `append` as if it returns a new array, but in fact, it modifies the existing array in place. It's a confusing error, because the `append` returns `()`, meaning it returns "nothing". So, the following line:

```
visited = visited.append(RowColumn(row: row, column: column))
```

Should be:

```
visited.append(RowColumn(row: row, column: column))
```

Also, RowColumn needs to conform to `Equatable`:

```
struct RowColumn : Equatable {
```